# error in generating and reading barcode for arabic letters

Tags: c#, barcode, arabic

I have tried to generate and scan barcode from textbox using MessagingToolkit.Barcode namespace. I tried an Arabic letter but I got this exception: Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
the codes for reading and generating barecode are:
reading barecode:

```
BarcodeDecoder scanner= new BarcodeDecoder();
enter code hereResult result = scanner.Decode(new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image));
MessageBox.Show(result.Text);
```

scanning:

```
BarcodeDecoder scanner = new BarcodeEncoder();
generator.IncludeLabel = true;
generator.CustomLabel = textBox1.Text;
if (textBox1.Text != "")
pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(generator.Encode(BarcodeFormat.Code93, textBox1.Text));
```

when I try to generate the barcode using Arabic letters, I got the exception that I mentioned above.

How can I fix the problem

Comment: What kind of Barcode library are you using?

Comment: MessagingToolkit.Barcode: https://blog.basseltech.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Barcode-DLL.zip

Comment: I'd probably contact the owner of the library and ask him about the problems when generating barcodes for arabic letters. It's possible the library (or barcodes in general...) don't support this.

Comment: Well, quite obviously using Code93 scheme for your barcode won't work with Arabic letters, because Code93 simply does not support arabic letters (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_93). You should first resarch which barcode schemes are capable of encoding arabic letters, only then you should go and research which barcode libraries support one (or multiple) of those barcode schemes ...

Comment: I am a beginner in this subject. So, may you help me if there is another library that can be useful?

Comment: I can't and i don't because i have no further knowledge of barcode schemes/symbologies used in different regions of the world. :-(  You are very well able to do the same research i would be able to do...

Comment: OK. thanks my friend 